# Linked List access violation in C

Tags: c, linked-list, access-violation

Im not sure i got the concept of Linked List properly. What im trying to do is to create a linked list which receives the integer 6 as it's first "data". instead i get this access violation error when trying to write in the integer into the first node's data. is there something specific i missed here?

```
    ///////////////////////////////

typedef struct List_Node
{
    int data;
    struct List_Node* next;
}List_Node;

typedef struct List
{
    List_Node* head;
}List;

////////////////////////////////


List* create_list();
void print_list(List_Node *x);
void add_to_node(List_Node *a,int val);

////////////////////////////////

void main()
{
    List *a = create_list();
    List_Node *ind = a->head;
    printf("List:\n");
    add_to_node(ind,6);
}

void print_list(List_Node *a)
{
    while(a != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \n",a->data);
        a = a->next;
    }
    return;
}

void add_to_node(List_Node *a,int val)
{
    a->data = val;
}

struct List* create_list()
{
struct List* list = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
list->head = NULL;
return list;
}
```

Comment: "Im not sure i got the concept of Linked List properly.", I think what you did not get properly, is *concept of pointer*. But good thing is, implementing a linked list is a good way to learn pointers.

Comment: usually we suggest beginners to use a debugger, but in this case it's so simple you can follow the code with paper and pencil...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is dereferencing a `NULL` pointer as `a->head` is `NULL`:

```
list->head = NULL; /* inside create_list()` and 'list' returned to ...*/

List_Node *ind = a->head; /* ... inside main(), and then passed to */
add_to_node(ind,6);       /* add_to_node() ... */

a->data = val;            /* and dereferenced inside add_to_node(). */
```

Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behaviour. To correct, `malloc()` memory for a `List_Node` and assign to `a->head`. Recommend creating an `add_node()` function that allocates memory and assigns the new `int` value to newly `malloc()`d node.

---

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

As all have pointed out, you are dereferencing a `NULL` pointer as your `list->head` contains `NULL`.

Another thing I should point out is that, you are creating a List. but not any Node. There is no node in the list. You have to allocate memory for a Node and then use it.

So, instead of `add_to_node()`, you may use a function `add_node` that will take the `list` or the `head` and the value as parameters, create a node(i.e. allocating memory for the node), set the value and add it to the list.

Also, in your case, the structure `List` is redundant as it contains only one member. instead you can simply use `List_node* head`.

Answer (score 1):

### What you are doing:

#### In `create_list`:

- Allocating memory for a `List` pointer.
- Setting the list's head to NULL.

#### In `add_to_node`:

- Setting the specified node pointer's `data` element to the specified `val`.

#### In `main`:

- Creating a `List` pointer `a` by calling `create_list`. This list has a NULL head.
- Initializing a `List_Node` pointer, `ind`, to point to the created list's head (which is NULL).
- Trying to set `ind`'s data element to 6 by calling `add_to_node`.

  - **This is where your program is causing the access violation exception.**
  - `ind` = NULL. Therefore `NULL->data` = undefined behaviour.

---

### What you should be doing:

#### In `create_list`:

- Allocate memory for a `List` pointer, say `linked_list`.
- Allocate memory for `linked_list`'s `head` pointer.
- For the `linked_list`'s `head`, initialize `data` and the `next` pointer to 0 and NULL respectively.

#### In `add_to_node`:

- Do the same thing you're doing now.

#### In `main`:

- Create a `List` pointer `a` by calling `create_list`. Now, this list will have a valid, initialized NULL head, but with no meaningful data.
- Set the list's head `data` by calling `add_to_node(a->head, 6);`.

**Note:** This will only ensure you have a head node in your list. Nowhere are you creating additional nodes.